# Magento 2 How to set owner email address to get new order email?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin-panel, order-email

I am Using Magento 2.1.1 version with em-everything default theme.If Any customer ordering the product from store the new order email is not sending to store-owner email id but customer is getting the new order email.How to set Store Owner email id to get mails on all new orders ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To receive all new orders e-mail you have set-up some Configuration in Admin, more specifically (Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Order -> Send Order Email Copy To), after you complete this field, you will receive a copy of every new order.